# How to show all images from a AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-s3 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepond to upload images to my AWS S3 bucket. I've got it running, but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to show all images in the AWS S3 bucket. I don't want to save each link to a image in a database and then run through that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Switched to package https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

Added some scripting:

```
<script>
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config.update({
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '/******'
  }),
  region: '/******'
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: { Bucket: 'gamesnap' }
})

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      baseUrl: 'https://******.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/',
      images: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    s3.listObjectsV2((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " , err);
      } else {
        this.images = data.Contents
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```